# pulling decimal data from database and storing in array

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, list, decimal

```
import MySQLdb

items = []
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '******' , db = '*******')

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT longitude FROM coordinates")

data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
    new_items = items[row]


print new_items
```

my database has 4 columns. an integer id, and three decimal rows called `longitude`, `latitude`, and `heading`. there are 4 sets of 'dummy' data in the database, and I am trying to be able to grab all 4 of those longitude data (they are of type decimal) and store them in some type of array.

I know my code is set up as a list right now, which is why I am getting an error that says lists only except integer data type... does anybody know how to store decimal data types as an array of some sort?

Comment: example of data variable output would be helpful

Comment: apologies, yes. I meant to say columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in data:
    items.append(float(row))
new_items = items
print(new_items)
```

Comment: this works without any errors, but the output looks like the following: [(Decimal('-75.14567854321567'),)]  ..... is their a way to get rid of all Decimal and other stuff (meaning I just want the negative decimal value to be printed)?

Comment: can you give complete output ?

Comment: [(Decimal('-75.14596502345678'),), (Decimal('-75.145678932567894'),), (Decimal('-75.14523567843256'),), (Decimal('-75.14567825609123'),)]

Comment: [get raw decimal value from mysqldb query](//stackoverflow.com/q/12661999)

Comment: @JayShankarGupta: This answer is getting flagged as low quality in the review queues; could you add some explanation to go with the code?

Comment: sorry all, was away from computer so did not have chance to check if this worked or not till now.... worked like a charm. Thanks much!